# Apply procedure to files in many subdirectories

Tags: python

I am trying to apply a procedure to thousands of files, but in many subdirectories.

I was thinking using `os.listdir()` first to list all subdirectories, than go look in each subdirectory and apply my procedure. My arborescence is as follow:

```
              subdir1 -> file, file, file, .....
              subdir2 -> file, file, file, .....
Directory  -> subdir3 -> file, file, file, .....
              subdir4 -> file, file, file, .....
              subdir5 -> file, file, file, .....
```

I can access the list of subdir with `os.listdir()` but not the files in the subdirectories, do you have an idea how to proceed ?
Thanks

EDIT:
When using MikeH method, in my case:

```
import os
from astropy.io import fits

ROOT_DIR='./'

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(ROOT_DIR):
    for fname in fileList:
        hdul = fits.open(fname)
```

I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lte08600-2.00+0.5.Alpha=+0.50.PHOENIX-ACES-AGSS-COND-2011-HiRes.fits'
```

And indeed if I try to check the path on the file, with `print(os.path.abspath(fname)` I can see that the path is wrong, it misses the subdirectories like /root/dir/fnam instead of root/dir/subdir/fname
What is wrong in this ?

EDIT2:
That's it I found out what was wrong, I have to join the path of the file, writing `os.path.join(dirName,fname)` instead of just `fname` each time.
Thanks !

Comment: Please share sample code that you've tried.

Comment: Use `os.walk()` [https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
import os
ROOT_DIR='./'

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(ROOT_DIR):
    for fname in fileList:
        # fully qualified file name is ROOT_DIR/dirname/fname
        performFunction(dirName, fname)
```

Comment: This seems to work, if I use the function ```print(fname)``` just to check I do have all the files in the sub directories, but I don't understand exactly how it works, could you explain please ?

Comment: In this case, when I check the path of each fname, it is incorrect as it has ./dir/fnam, without the subdir